# Are there any libraries for resizing a photo to a square

Tags: android, photo, libraries

Are there any libraries for resizing a photo to a square (similar to instagram)?
So the user can choose what is visible/size of the square by swiping and resizing a grid.

Anyone here familiar with a librarie for this purpose?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it :)

https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

**EDIT**

There is a build in crop intent:

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
```